# Is it more efficient to use an object data stream or a primitive data stream in Java?

Tags: java, object, io, stream

When performing I/O operations in Java, is it generally more efficient (in terms of computing resources) to use an object data stream like `ObjectInputStream` or is it more efficient to use a primitive data stream like `DataInputStream`?

If it is more efficient to use an object data stream, is an object data stream still more efficient when we take into account the overhead (as minimal as it may be) associated with creating the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ObjectInputStream will be simpler to use.  I would check this won't be fast enough before going to the effort of using DataInputStream. DataInputStream is not as efficient as using NIO/ByteBuffer but the effort increases for a relatively small improvement.

Answer (score 4):

Custom serialization can save you space/bandwidth and cpu time, if done right.

I suggest you take a look at google's [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/) - very efficient and portable serialization library.

Answer (score 3):

You choose an Object or Data InputStream based on what kind of data is actually in your stream. If it's Java Objects use an Object stream, if it's not then a DataInputStream (or other as appropriate).

So what kind of data do you have in your stream?

Comment: I have a choice.  I can make a new class and put the data in an object, or I an send it as primitive data.  I am trying to figure out which is more efficient.

Comment: then write some benchmarks and figure it out. Efficency is the *last* thing to look at here. More important elements are things like what other languages might need to interact with this system. Will it always be only Java or will you need to connect it with .NET or Perl or X? Because that would have a major influence on the choice you make. If only ever Java I would recommend the OO approach and go with OOS.

Comment: ByteBuffer or ObjectOutput/InputStream (or bust). Besides, if one knows how to properly write a micro benchmark would never ask the question, microbenchmarks are one of the hardest simple things to do in Java.

Comment: You are thinking about the wrong kind of efficiency. Ifbyou were thinking about developer efficiency, then you would not have asked this question. You would have asked "what is the least work I have to do to get my object across the network" then somebody would have said, xstream over tcp - or something similar - and you would have had it finished and tested by now!

Answer (score 2):

Object serialization/desirialization is one of the heavier things there are in java. So if this is a performance critical part of your program then avoiding object serialization can help. Although in many cases the bottlenecks lie somewhere else and you might end up doing premature optimization. So IMHO if you don't know for sure that this is going to be a bottleneck use ObjectInputStream and optimize later.

Comment: It's also a good idea to keep the serialization/object transfer business separated from the rest of the code in case you do need to switch to a differnet method it later.

Answer (score 1):

Why Don't you write something that does what you want, put some tests around it so you know it works. Then if it ever becomes a problem, you will be able to replace the implementation with something quicker, with no fuss and bother. If it turns out that it's not an issue, as most things like this turn out to be...then you won't have spent time on something unnecessary, and you won't have prematurely optimised.

XstreamIs pretty handy fire this kind of thing, and very easy to use.

if your architecture isn't unduely chatty you may never need to optimise this bit.